# Resize / enlarge program open file dialog boxes

Tags: windows

XP Pro, SP3. Is it possible to resize PERMANENTLY program "File > Open" dialog boxes? (I know it's possible to hold down the Ctrl button whilst resizing but the new size is not "remembered")

Answer (score 2):

[**File-Ex**](http://www.file-ex.com/welcome.html) can enlarge the size of the default open/save dialog boxes and adds also several other features.

- Automatically enhances almost all Windows applications, saving you valuable time.
- Larger file window reduces scrolling clicks by up to 90%.
- Re-opens the last folder used so you don't have to hunt for it each time you open a file.
- Default to the sorting you like, and have it remember the column widths in details view.
- Remembers 100 recent and favorite folders / files, reducing clicks to the file you need.
- Create and open a new folders with fewer steps -- opens to the new folder automatically.
- Built-in Find tool searches all of your hard drives for files.
- ...and more!
- (Works in all versions of Windows from 95 to XP)

[**FileOpenPatcher**](http://www.netcult.ch/elmue/ElmueSoft-en.htm) can enlarge the Open dialog, by patching the relevant DLL. This one is free.

Comment: You sound like a sales pitch. Other than that, this is probably the best solution. +1 to give you your 2000. Congrats.

Comment: Sales pitch, while listing a free one? ;-)
Thanks for the +1 and the congrats!

Answer (score 2):

[FileBox eXtender](http://www.hyperionics.com/files/index.asp), an open-source product,  will resize the file dialog, in addition to extending its functionality with a "Favorites" menu and a "Recent Folders" menu.